# I am adding one Vserv Full Screen SDK to my IOS project but i face one problem

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I am trying to add one Vserv Full Screen SDK in my ios application but I get following error and warning

Error:-"_OBJC_CLASS_$_VservAdManager", referenced from: objc-class-ref-to-VservAdManager in   VservFullScreenSDKUsageDemoViewController.old: symbol(s) not found

warning:- directory '/Users/macintoshuser/Desktop/VservFullScreenSDK_Iphone' following -L not found

Comment: Thats interesting, but how did this one go? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996260/i-am-adding-one-framework-to-my-project-but-i-face-one-problem

Comment: Please don't ask the same question multiple times. Thanks.

Comment: So, could you solve this problem with the suggested linker flags? If not, you should provide more details so we can be more helpful.

Comment: @gcbrueckmann  
Have you integrated Vserv Full Screen SDK yet ? Can you tell me how to resolve this situtation

Answer (score 1):

Non-Apple frameworks aren’t supported on iOS. Is what you call a framework, in fact, a static library? If so, you may need to add `-ObjC` and `-all_load` to the `Other Link Flags` build setting of the app target.

Comment: Have you integrated  Vserv Full Screen SDK yet ? I've also met this bug ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set **armv6** architecture to get this work.

> Project-->Build Setting-->Architecture-->armv6

**Note** that you need to delete default setting for architecture and then type **armv6** to add required one.